# How to assign probabilities in SelectOutput5 based on agent type?

Tags: anylogic

I have agents of 2 different types entering a SelectOutput5 block. How can I code it so
`if (agent instanceof FollowUp)` then the probabilities of exit 1,2,3,4,5 are .70,.30,0,0,0 respectively. Then the same thing for `if (agent instanceof NewConsult)` with probabilities of the respective exits as .50,.50,0,0,0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply write the following in the first probability field:

```
agent instanceof Followup ? 0.70 : 0.50
```

Repeat the same for each other one.

Another possible idea (less efficient and not recommended) but which you might find interesting is to have a single selectOutput with the condition being:

```
agent instanceof Followup
```

After that block, add two selectOutput5 blocks, each with the desired set of probabilities.

Comment: In respect to your first option, wouldn't it have to be 
Probability 1:
agent instanceof Followup ? 0.70        
agent instanceof NewConsult ? .50

Probability 2:
agent instanceof Followup ? .30       
agent instanceof NewConsult ? .50

Comment: Yes, but in that case you need to add ":" followed by a 3rd default probability. I assumed you only have 2 agents types. If it's not the first, then it has to be the second.

Comment: You're also missing ":" after the 0.70.

Comment: Ah ok, so each probability block will have the probabilities of each agent type inside it?

Comment: I think you're talking about the second option? I will rephrase for using just one selectOutput5 block. When an agent enters, the probabilities for each out port (1 to 5) are calculated and a decision is made accordingly. So if you write `agent instanceof Followup ? 0.70 : 0.50` in the first probability field, then if it's an agent of type Followup, probability for that first out port is 0.7, otherwise (i.e. not Followup so consequently NewConsult?), then the probability becomes 0.5. The same applies and should be repeated for every probability field. Let me know if something is still unclear.